# If electromagnetic wave traval in straight line, how can it be like wavefronts spreading out and each point behaving as source for new wavefront? How?

Tags: electromagnetism

How can electromagnetic wave (oscillating straight electric and magnetic fields) be related to curved wave fronts?

Comment: Waves are not rays.  Rays usually are straight lines.  Waves aren't lines at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine two circles spreading out from two nearby centres. The circles spread out in a circular fashion, but the two points where they intersect both move in a straight line.

Now process that thought, and keep learning ...